# Header element being hidden in IE8

Tags: css, html, internet-explorer-8

I am working on www.doublegbobcat.com/preview and I have used a header element. Things are displaying as intended, except in IE8, where the header seems to be getting hidden on the z-index behind other content. How can I get the header element to display in IE8 the way it is in Chrome?

thx

Answer (score 5):

The header element isn't showing up in IE8 developer tools, even though you've declared the new HTML 5 elements for IE lt 9

Instead, try including the HTML 5 "Shiv" script in your `<head>`

[Link to script](http://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/)

[More info](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML5_Shiv)

Comment: There is always a `body` element in an HTML document. There may or may not be a `<body>` tag; it is never required (except when serving a document with an XHTML doctype), and adding it has no effect.

Comment: OK great, I added <!--[if lt IE 9]>
     <script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]--> to the top of each page, but then it didnt start working until I added the body tags, not sure how that happened lol!

Answer (score 0):

IE8 will not accept the HTML5  tag. You'll need to use conditional statements to replace it.

http://fortuito.us/diveintohtml5/semantics.html#unknown-elements